# Is there any way to put the Google Tag manager Identification code into the child theme?

Tags: child-theme, google

I know how to create child theme for wordpress theme but having problem in installing Google Tag Manager into the child theme. Normally there are two files in the child theme directory (one is stylesheet css and another one is function.php) however, Google suggests to put the identification code into the header.php file, so in this case is there any way to put the identification code of Google Tag manager into the child theme.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options -

1. Install a plugin that adds GTM for you. This makes it very easy, but it does add another plugin to the site. Site Kit supposedly slows down a site more than you would expect.
2. Make a copy of header.php and put it in your child theme folder. Now you can make edits to this file without the edits being overwritten when the parent theme is updated. That's how the child theme works. Anything you want to edit gets copied into the child theme. By default you only get the stylesheet and functions.php, but you can put any theme file into the child theme for editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin for adding the tag. Google's official [Site Kit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-site-kit/) or [WP Global Site Tag](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-global-site-tag/) by Digital Apps could help.